# System settings suddenly locked to defaults

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, settings, system

I accidentally pulled the power cable from my laptop, which is without its battery, during a session of Ubuntu 14.04, causing a hard shutdown. I then plugged the cable back, turned the laptop back on, and waited for two checks of my hard drive for errors, which ended "finding errors" and offering me to "press F" to attempt to fix them, which I did.

As I logged into my user, I noticed that not only were the launcher icons at their default size, the only icons in the launcher were the default ones that come in a fresh install. Moving them or unlocking them doesn't seem to work, as the icons just go back to where they were, and locking icons of other applications makes them appear in the launcher, only to just disappear less than a second later. **All my installed applications remain working without problems.**

Not only that, but attempting to change any system settings via the GUI tool gives me the visual feedback that a change has been made, but in a fraction of a second it goes back to the original, default setting.

Did I lose any kind of configuration file during that hard reset? Is there any way to restore my desktop to how it was?

Comment: You could check whether you still have write permission on files in e.g. ~/.config. Though I can't think of any reason why these would change, and it more or less sounds like you are logged in as a different user.

Comment: Just tested it, I can write files anywhere within my home folder (and I'm using the same user as before, I never created any other). It just seems that changes to any system settings or to Unity's disposition are instantly overridden by their defaults.

Comment: If you create a new user, does it have the same problem???

Comment: @Fabby, I created a new user to test if the problem occurs, and it doesn't. Changing any settings works fine in that user. 
Fortunately enough, creating the new user via GUI did work.

Comment: I attempted to change some settings (namely disabling the touchpad) via dconf-editor, but that also didn't work.

Comment: An old fart's suggestion: If the user profile give you problems, copy the files over from the user profile that doesn't work to the one that does...  If it happens a second time, *only then* investigate...  If you agree, let me know and I'll post it as an answer (which you can then accept, having both your and my reputation go up)